# Word Processor in Silverlight?

Tags: pdf, silverlight-4.0, docx, word-processor

Are there any free & decent word processors in Silverlight 4? Would this be feasible in Silverlight?

Also, are there any free libraries for reading PDF/DOCX in Silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

Free word processors, yes. Decent? Well....

Check out the ultimate free word processor for SL4: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426926(VS.95).aspx. There were a number of pre-SL4 ones out there, but since the sample uses the RichTextBox, it's the best place to start. It's decent-ish.

On reading PDFs, I don't know of any. On reading the DOCX format, check out [TextGlow](http://textglow.codeplex.com/). It's not 100%, but handles the most common formatting.